# Hana Text Search over different tables with different weights

Tags: hana

We are wondering whether *SAP Hana* supports a text search over entities whose texts are in different tables (e.g. the entity *"Product 42"* references one text in table A and two texts in table B). We want to assign a different weight to each hit depending on the table in which this hit was found, e.g. when the search term was found in table A this counts more than when it was found in table B.

It seems that using the predicate *"contains()"* this cannot be realized. The *"SAP HANA Search Developer Guide"* [1] states on page 46 that all columns listed in *contains()* have to belong to the same table.

Is there an *"Application Function Library" (AFL)* that offers such functionality for text search?

Thank you and kind regards, Michael

[1] http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Search_Developer_Guide_en.pdf, Document Version: 1.0 - 2014-11-26.

Comment: It says same table *or view* so you could create a view with all the columns you wish to search.  Don't know if that really helps on the weighting part though.

Comment: Ok, to get the weighting you can create two views of your base tables, each with a different weight, then UNION the tables into a Calculated view.  This should give you your properly weighted results from both tables.

Comment: @MichaelGardner: Thank you for your comments. 
In the meanwhile we found out that Attribute Views support the definition of different weights for the individual attributes ("Data Foundation", select an attribute in view "Output", tab "Search Properties" in view "Properties", property "Weights for Ranking" ). However, when searching on this Attribute View then no hit is found for the search term "foo bar" when "foo" and "bar" are contained in DIFFERENT records with the SAME key in the SAME table.

Comment: Glad you found it.  I was unsure if you could define different weights in the same view.  Are you doing a Freestyle search (`where contains(*,'foo bar', FUZZY`) ?  Freestyle is the only way to go through multiple columns, but it must be enabled for the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I found out that a weighted text search with Hana can be realized as follows:

- Create an *Attribute View* which contains the relevant text columns from different tables.
- Ensure that all text attributes/columns are selected as output, i.e. they should appear in the view *"Output"* under *"Columns"* when *"Data Foundation"* is chosen in the view *"Scenario"*. You might also want to have at least one key attribute as output.
- Click on each of the text attributes in view *"Output"* under *"Columns"*. The properties for this attribute should be displayed in view *"Property"*. Select tab *"Search Properties"* in this view and set property *"Freestyle Search"* to *"True"* and enter a value for property *"Weights for Ranking"*.

After this you can perform a text search using this attribute view with SQL, for example:

```
SELECT score(), key_attribute ... 
       FROM "_SYS_BIC"."SOME.PACKAGE/MY_ATTRIBUTE_VIEW" 
       WHERE contains( ( attribute1, attribute2, ... ), 'search term' )
       ...
       ORDER by score() DESC;
```

Please note the different types of quotation marks used in the *FROM clause* and around the search term.

Answer (score 0):

you can also create a search rule set (referenced in the search developer guide) to annotate different weights and fuzziness thresholds for each column. the search rule set will reference an attribute view and within the attribute view you can include multiple tables